# How do I decrypt BitLocker-encrypted external hard drive on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, external-hdd

I have a 1TB Transcend external Hard drive, which is already encrypted with BitLocker (Windows feature for encrypting drives), I removed my Windows OS and now using Ubuntu 14.04 but unfortunately couldn't access my external hard drive on Ubuntu 14.04, if anyone knows the solution please help me.

regards

Comment: Do you have the password?

Comment: Yes I have its key  ( Dishank )

Comment: Sorry Utmankhail, I am not be able to help you right now. But, I am searching for an answer to your problem

Comment: Do you have access to another windows system?

Comment: Yes, I have but I want to decrypt it in Ubuntu  (Bellini)

Comment: This thread seems to provide a solution:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/617950/use-windows-bitlocker-encrypted-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use (Windows) BitLocker-encrypted drive on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617950/use-windows-bitlocker-encrypted-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried dislocker? Looks promising: http://www.hsc.fr/ressources/outils/dislocker/download/