# Use (Windows) BitLocker-encrypted drive on Ubuntu

Tags: windows, encryption, crossplatform

How could I mount my BitLocker encrypted drive on Ubuntu?

I have checked the [Wine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_%28software%29) website, and it had no BitLocker support, and I have no idea how to install Dislocker on my computer.

I can not remove the encryption because my school computers use Windows OS instead of Linux OS. Also because I installed Ubuntu because my Windows OS was not working.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Since Ubuntu 18.04, Dislocker is available in the Ubuntu Universe packages.  It can be installed using

```
sudo apt install dislocker
```

You may need to

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
```

---

> First, we make two folders, `/media/bitlocker` and `/media/mount`:
>
> ```
> sudo mkdir /media/bitlocker /media/mount
> ```
>
> Then, download and then extract [Dislocker](https://github.com/Aorimn/dislocker).
>
> You'll want to install some needed packages:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install libfuse-dev
> ```
>
> To install it, we need to change directory to the `dislocker` folder:
>
> ```
> cd dislocker
> ```
>
> Depending on your operating system, you'll need to choose one of
> these:
>
> - For Debian-like distos based on Debian Jessie or Ubuntu 14.04 or older:
>
>   ```
>    aptitude install gcc cmake make libfuse-dev libpolarssl-dev ruby-dev
>   ```
> - For Debian-like distos based on Debian Stretch or Ubuntu 16.04 or later:
>
>   ```
>    aptitude install gcc cmake make libfuse-dev libmbedtls-dev ruby-dev
>   ```
>
> Now we finally install dislocker:
>
> ```
> cmake .
> make
> sudo make install
> ```

Here, we need to find our partition so we dont erase all of our drives accidentally:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

If we have a recovery password, we can decrypt it using this:

```
sudo dislocker -r -V /dev/sdaX -p 1536987-000000-000000-000000-000000-000000-000000-000000 -- /media/bitlocker
```

PS: You should replace `1536987-000000-000000-000000-000000-000000-000000-000000` with your recovery password.

If you know your password, we can just use that too:

```
sudo dislocker -r -V /dev/sdaX -u yourPassword -- /media/bitlocker
```

If your disk is mounted to sdb, use option sdb1.

If you are decrypting with a recovery file then use "path/to/.BEK" instead:

```
sudo dislocker-fuse -V /dev/sdcX -f /media/user/usb-drive/00000000-0X0X-0XX0-XXX0-XXXX0XXX00XX.BEK -- /media/bitlocker
```

Now, we finally mount our file:

```
sudo -i
cd /media/bitlocker
mount -r -o loop dislocker-file /media/mount
```

(If the mount above fails with "Permission denied" add the `-r` option and try again.)

Now you can move to the /media/mount folder and see your decrypted data.

Read [the source](http://theevilbit.blogspot.com/2014/04/using-dislocker-to-mount-bitlocker.html) for more information and details.

Comment: I don't have recovery password. And I'm not sure where to get this from. Can you tell me about this ?

Comment: I also needed this: `sudo apt-get install libpolarssl-dev` - otherwise make would fail.

Comment: Does this also allow for writing  to the bitlockered drive as well as reading?

Comment: nazar@android:~/dislocker$ cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 6.2.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Could NOT find POLARSSL (missing:

Comment: nazar@android:~/dislocker$ sudo apt-get install libpolarssl-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libpolarssl-dev

Comment: failed on ubuntu 16.10

Comment: `sudo fdisk -l` lists `/dev/sdb1` to `/dev/sdb3` even though there is no partition on the USB-Stick. Also the dislocker command does not work on any of them

Comment: dislocker should support read-write (rw) access to some bitlocker containers/versions, "the source" link says windows 8 rw access wasn't supported yet (in 2014) and a comment says it would *"silently mount as ro (even though mount shows as rw)"* probably leading to the mount error *"ntfs-3g-mount: mount failed: Permission denied"*. Omitting the `-r` option to dislocker & mount should try mounting rw

Comment: I don't think method works anymore for discs cyrpted with newer Bitlocker introduced in Windows 10. `sudo fdisk -l` doesn't even recognize the disk drive. I can only think of this is why.

Comment: In case you get -like me- a `/usr/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/ruby.h:24:10: fatal error: ruby/config.h: No such file or directory
 #include "ruby/config.h"` just use `sudo cp /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/config.h /usr/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/`

Comment: on debian-based systems ther is simpler way to install: sudo apt install dislocker

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: It worked fine on Ubuntu 20.04 too! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8):

You need Dislocker to use BitLocker-encrypted drives. You can download it from [here](http://www.hsc.fr/ressources/outils/dislocker/) or there is a GitHub [repository](https://github.com/Aorimn/dislocker/tree/develop) also.

To install it you will need:

- A compiler, [GCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) or [Clang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang);
- [Make](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29) (or gmake, for FreeBSD)
- Headers for FUSE;
- Headers for PolarSSL;
- A partition encrypted with BitLocker, from Windows Vista, 7 or 8.

For detailed instructions, see [this](https://github.com/Aorimn/dislocker/blob/develop/INSTALL.txt) page or refer to `install.txt` file in the downloaded Dislocker archive.

Comment: Did you *really* have to link to the Wikipedia page about GitHub?

Answer (score 6):

Very good tutorial, however there's one problem. Since the file is read only you will need to use the read-only flag:

```
mount -ro loop dislocker-file /media/mount
```

Also the -u (--user-password) option to make this **much** easier:

```
sudo dislocker -r -V /dev/sdaX -u -- /media/mount
Enter the user password:▯
```

If you want to mount again in the same folder use:

```
sudo dislocker -r -V /dev/sdaX -u -- -o nonempty /media/mount
```

(Where X should be replaced by the number of your encrypted drive, e.g. /dev/sda7)

Comment: Also, do NOT use `make uninstall` for this package. It will break your symlinks and it will look like your /usr/bin has been deleted and you will think you will have to reinstall your distro however the files are all there after you reboot. I can't find the page that helped me fix this problem however there are other problems with the Makefile that the maintainer should be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Modern versions of Ubuntu/Kubuntu can decrypt BitLocker partitions without extra software.

At least, I've tested in Kubuntu 22.04 (and everything is fine).

Answer (score 0):

I installed dislocker recently and running the script `cmake .` triggered errors on trying to find `polarssl` despite it being installed.

By chance, I eventually managed to install it: you should not run `cmake` under `/dislocker/src` directory as mentioned in the first reply (maybe it worked in the past) but should:

```
cd /dislocker
cmake .
```

Comment: Maybe `make` works in dislocker/src, while `cmake` doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

the new package name for libpolarssl is: libmbedtls-dev

so you can install the libpolarssl compoments for cmake by installing it:

```
apt-get install libmbedtls-dev
```

Then cname and everything else will work fine

Comment: So this and all older solutions entail that the encryption key is fully stored on the drive itself, rather than part of it being stored only on the TPU of the motherboard as is the case with BitLocker itself, right?