# Remove Bitlocker encryption on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: encryption, 16.04

How to access bitlocker encrypted drive in Ubuntu 16.04?
Dislocker utility worked in 14.04 but a package which dislocker depends libpolarssl is missing in 16.04. Is there any workaround or any other utility?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use (Windows) BitLocker-encrypted drive on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](http://askubuntu.com/questions/617950/use-windows-bitlocker-encrypted-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Comment: @AndroidDev That worked in 14.04, but is not working in 16.04

Comment: it was working fine with th git help. what is the command to access the encrypted drive.

Answer (score 5):

You can install polarssl and dislocker on Ubuntu 16.04 
by following [TuxDiary - dislocker: decrypt BitLocker encrypted volumes](https://tuxdiary.com/2015/03/20/dislocker/).

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install libmbedcrypto0 libmbedtls-dev libfuse-dev
```

If git is not installed on your system you can install git by running the following command. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install git
```

Then you can install dislocker from source using git. Open the terminal and type the below commands.

```
git clone https://github.com/Aorimn/dislocker.git
cd dislocker
cmake .
make
sudo make install
```

Now you can start using dislocker. It works fine.