# Ubuntu Encryption, Partition Size and NTFS Access

Tags: partitioning

I have following questions with respect to Ubuntu Desktop OS:

1. How to successfully encrypt Ubuntu OS which is being dual booted with Windows 10?
2. How to make NTFS Formatted and BitLocker enabled partition to be accessible in Ubuntu?
3. What is recommended partition scheme for Ubuntu Desktop i.e. /boot, swap and /, etc. especially keeping in mind that Ubuntu installed will be dual booted with Windows 10?
4. What is recommended partition size for Ubuntu Desktop i.e. for /boot, swap and /, etc. especially keeping in mind that Ubuntu installed will be dual booted with Windows 10?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. To install Ubuntu with encryption alonside another operating system, see [How can I install Ubuntu encrypted with LUKS with dual-boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293028/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-encrypted-with-luks-with-dual-boot). It's about 13.04 but the same principles apply.
2. See [Remove Bitlocker encryption on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766476/remove-bitlocker-encryption-on-ubuntu-16-04). (Disregard the title, it is about accessing BitLocker-encrypted disks.)
3. With encryption the partitioning scheme uses two partitions, one for `/boot` and one for a LUKS container containing a LVM physical volume containing a LVM  volume group containing at least two logical volumes -- one for `/` and one for the paging space. (Or at least one, because you can dispense with the swap volume if you are willing to create a swap file.)
4. `/boot` needs 250 to 500 MiB. For the rest of the system you need about 20 to 25 GiB plus how much space you want for your files, documents, pictures, projects etc. How big or small to make the swap volume depends on the specific use; for example, if you want to hibernate Ubuntu the swap volume needs to be somewhat larger than physical RAM; if you don't want to hibernate Ubuntu the swap space can be quite small, depending on your expected workload.

Comment: 1.  I have tried the option you suggested, it ran perfectly.  But, the link does not show how to mount the partition to use it.  I used following to do that which fails with error

Comment: Do you mean how to use dislocker? [dislocker: decrypt BitLocker encrypted volumes](https://tuxdiary.com/2015/03/20/dislocker/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yes, the dislocker-file does not copy into /media/bitlcoker directory.  The link you shared only shows how to install dislocker.  It does not show the process to make it accessible.  I following another article from this forum for that. I want to provide feedback on other questions as well, but this window only allow certain characters!  Since, they are not answers, I should not use "Answer Your Question" option as that would be confusing to others.  So, how can I reply so that I can fit feedback of all four questions?

Comment: Since, I could not find an option to reply to the thread, I will try to do it bit by bit using Comment option.

Comment: Reply Starts Here:

Comment: 1.  Thanks for the reply and sharing the thread.  If you look closely, people are suggesting certain steps to be skipped (12, 14 and 15) seems to be consensus.  What do you suggest? Also, / and /boot are requirements for LUKS, but what about swap, should I not create it through GParted at Step 2?

Comment: @Ubuntu Junkie -- It's your system, you partition it the way you want. You should _always_ read the tutorial, make sure that you understand what's going on and only afterwards apply the principles. Never follow a procedure or type a command if you are not sure that you understand what it does. Personally, I always make a separate swap volume. And I always make it small -- I never hibernate computers.

Comment: 2.  Thanks for the reply and sharing the thread.  It worked like a charm for installation, but since the process of accessing BitLocker partition is not mentioned in the link, I followed this link (http://askubuntu.com/questions/617950/use-windows-bitlocker-encrypted-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts), but I get this error "bad mount point `340494-622281-330704-717959-621588-030624-688204-117634': No such file or directory" on the "Now you can decrypt using" step.  Any suggestions? OR steps to follow for mounting?

Comment: 3.  Thanks for the reply and sharing your thoughts.  So, /boot and / are absolutely necessary even if there is already operating system installed with load in MBR.  Kindly, confirm? Also, I have 32 GB of memory in my Laptop, so what do you think my swap size should be?  I am also not a believer in Hibernation, what are your general thoughts about it?

Comment: 4.  Thanks; appreciate it.  If installed with all the packages, how much space would it consume? i.e. the / partition?  Would 30 GB be enough?

Comment: 5.  Adding this question as well.  What are your thoughts on Encrypting SSD?  Is it overkill to do encryption on SSD?