# unable to access external HDD

Tags: hard-drive

I am new to Ubuntu. I've just loaded Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm unable to access my external HDD.

[image: screen shot]
[image: screen shot .]

`$ sudo fdisk -lu`

```
Disk /dev/ram0: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram1: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram2: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram3: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram4: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram5: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram6: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram7: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram8: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram9: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram10: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram11: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram12: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram13: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram14: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram15: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 149.1 GiB, 160041885696 bytes, 312581808 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x4b60f5df

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 304390143 304388096 145.1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       304392190 312580095   8187906   3.9G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       304392192 312580095   8187904   3.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris


Disk /dev/sdb: 1.8 TiB, 2000398929920 bytes, 488378645 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 268431360 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x7c90f7fc

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *     2048 488378644 488376597  1.8T  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

`$ sudo parted -l`

```
Model: ATA WDC WD1600BEKT-6 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 160GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  156GB  156GB   primary   ext4            boot
 2      156GB   160GB  4192MB  extended
 5      156GB   160GB  4192MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)


Model: Seagate Expansion Desk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      8389kB  2000GB  2000GB  primary               boot
```

`$ sudo blkid`

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="5f051edf-54d0-4f09-a465-8545f98af9e2" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="4b60f5df-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="bfe37172-b5b5-4c6c-9942-5af4bb249cab" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="4b60f5df-05"
/dev/sdb1: PARTUUID="7c90f7fc-01"
```

`$ df`

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             1954436       0   1954436   0% /dev
tmpfs             394748    6316    388432   2% /run
/dev/sda1      149673244 4473872 137573288   4% /
tmpfs            1973724     184   1973540   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120       4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            1973724       0   1973724   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs             394748     100    394648   1% /run/user/1000
```

`$ sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1/media/bal007`

```
mount: can't find /dev/sdb1/media/bal007 in /etc/fstab
```

this external HDD was working fine with Windows 7 earlier

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a space between `/dev/sdb1` and `/media/bal007`. The hint is in the message displayed by **mount**: `can't find` **`/dev/sdb1/media/bal007`** `in /etc/fstab`.

Comment: after keeping space it gives   NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdb1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?

Comment: also tried replacing sdb1 with sdb but again same message

Comment: @balu singh: What does `sudo file -s /dev/sdb /dev/sdb1` say?

Comment: /dev/sdb:  DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1 : ID=0x7, active, start-CHS (0x0,32,33), end-CHS (0x3ff,254,63), startsector 2048, 488376597 sectors
/dev/sdb1: DOS/MBR boot sector, code offset 0x58+2, OEM-ID "-FVE-FS-", Bytes/sector 4096, reserved sectors 0, Media descriptor 0xf8, sectors/track 63, heads 255, hidden sectors 2048, FAT (32 bit), sectors/FAT 8160, serial number 0x0, unlabeled; NTFS, sectors/track 63, physical drive 0x1fe0, $MFT start cluster 393217, serial number 02020454d414e204f, checksum 0x41462020

Comment: Your disk is encrypted with BitLocker: `OEM-ID "-FVE-FS-"`. See [Use (Windows) BitLocker-encrypted drive on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](http://askubuntu.com/questions/617950/use-windows-bitlocker-encrypted-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts).

Comment: tried the link      but got 
Sun Dec  4 16:34:00 2016 [CRITICAL] None of the provided decryption mean is decrypting the keys. Abort.
Sun Dec  4 16:34:00 2016 [CRITICAL] Unable to grab VMK or FVEK. Abort.

Comment: Try the Dislocker issues, https://github.com/Aorimn/dislocker.

Comment: i finally took the longer route. downloaded windows trial version. unlocked my drive and again installed ubuntu. now it is working fine. finally i found that the bitlocker in windows is needs to be decryprted first. thanks for all your options.