# BitLocker / Dislocker on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, encryption

In order to use an USB-Stick encrypted with Bitlocker I installed Dislocker on my Ubuntu 16.04 according to [Use (Windows) BitLocker-encrypted drive on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/a/617989/230083).

Unfortunately I cannot decrypt:

- `sudo fdisk -l` lists 4 Partitions even though there is only one partition on the USB-stick. And the size is wrong too. (The Disks Utility shows also only one partition.
- `sudo dislocker -r -V /dev/sdb4 -uMyPassword -- /media/bitlocker` does not mount any of the 4 listed partitions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed it using the command

```
sudo dislocker -r -V /dev/sdb -uMyPassword -- /media/bitlocker
```

(no number after /dev/sdb)

Answer (score 1):

When I try this, everything goes fine until I try to enter the mount folder. Then the following error shows up:

> The chosen directory /media/bitlocker is not a valid

If you are running in the same problem, you will have to mount the file *dislocker-file* inside the folder with something like this:

```
mount -ro loop dislocker-file /media/bitlocker-mount/
```

+Don't forget to `mkdir` a new folder to mount to.