# Reading bitlocker protected file system from Linux

Tags: windows-10

I have a Surface pro 3 and I tried to dual boot it, but I have done something wrong and now it just boots to UEFI.

I have all my life inside this little SSD and I know I'm sooo stupid because I didn't back it up and now it's encrypted.

I have booted it to Ubuntu using USB flash drive and pressed the TRY UBUNTU so I won't lose my data

So Anybody please could tell me how to decrypt it so I could recover my data back?

I have the encryption key

Comment: Have you tried Dislocker? https://github.com/Aorimn/dislocker/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 5):

After booting into the ubuntu the live cd, enable the universe repository

**settings > software and update > ubuntu software > tick community maintained software**

update the local repo and install some needed packages:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install dislocker libfuse-dev
```

make two folders, /media/bitlocker and /media/mount:

```
sudo mkdir /media/bitlocker /media/mount
```

find the encrypted windows partition:

```
lsblk
```

you would see something like

```
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      179:0    0  58.2G  0 disk 
├─sda1   179:1    0   200M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   179:2    0  54.3G  0 part /
```

per the sizes you can predict your windows partition

decrypt that **partition** with your bitlocker password:

```
sudo dislocker -r -V /dev/sdaX -u -- /media/mount
```

followed by password

OR

```
sudo dislocker -r -V /dev/sdaX -uPASSWORD -- /media/bitlocker
```

Replace PASSWORD with your bitlocker password

In case you want to use the recovery password instead, we can decrypt it using that:

```
sudo dislocker -r -V /dev/sdXY <recov_pass> --  /media/bitlocker
sudo dislocker -r -V /dev/sdaX -p1536987-000000-. . .-000000-000000 -- /media/bitlocker
```

replace 1536987-000000-. . .-000000-000000 with your recovery password

Now, we finally mount:

```
sudo -i
cd /media/bitlocker
mount -r -o loop dislocker-file /media/mount
```

Now you can move to the /media/mount folder and see your decrypted data

For detailed answer look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/875982/bitlocker-dislocker-on-ubuntu-16-04) and [that answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617950/use-windows-bitlocker-encrypted-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository universe` to add `universe` from the cmdline.

Answer (score 1):

[ptetteh227's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1024765/790920) was just the fix I needed. Just an FYI for anyone else.

```
mount -r -o loop dislocker-file /media/mount
```

did not work for me.

```
mount -o ro,loop /media/bitlocker/dislocker-file /media/mount
```

worked and I was able to access the data off the encrypted volume.