# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Windows 10 Pro BitLocker dualboot loop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, windows-10

Greeting's, following is my laptop configuration including OS installation:

1. SSD - 180 GB - Windows 10 Pro with systemroot drive (C:) - **Encrypted - BitLocker ON.**
2. HDD - 1 TB - 5 partitions:
   A. 50 GB - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS - ext4 file system.
   B. 10 GB - SWAP space for Ubuntu
   C, D and E - are NTFS partition - **PLAINTEXT (BitLocker off).** which I use only in windows.

When the system boots GRUB 2.02 beta takes over. I see Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with few options related to it and Windows 10 as DEV/SDA1/.

Here is the issue:

At times when I select windows, it boots normally and goes to BitLocker screen for password. However, **more often than not it shows redraws the blank background (color resembling that of ubuntu grub screen earlier and just stay there.** Only way for me to come out of this is to reboot the system.

Both the systems are fully patched as of this writing.

What can I do ensure a smooth boot cycle and not a hit or miss.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Following is the solution I've found, tested and currently using without any further problems.

As I click on "Windows" option, everything should be transferred to windows (boot sequence, POST, etc.). This concludes that the problem is before Windows bootloader and hence I edited following file to disable graphics for GRUB.

Boot into Ubuntu, open terminal and type:

`sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

```
#Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only) (remove the # before GRUB_TERMINAL line)

GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

Update GRUB settings using:

`sudo update-grub`

and you're done!

PS: My system has on-board Intel graphics processor and Nvidia GTX graphic card (i've installed drivers in both windows and Ubuntu).

Comment: Thanks! Amazing. I could already see through os-prober and [this answer, that dislocker worked](https://askubuntu.com/a/617989/820103), but it was just this simple.