# Permission issues using Dislocker for Bitlocker-encrypted drive on ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: encryption, ntfs

First of all I am a newcomer in Ubuntu. I want to use my bit-locker encrypted internal hard drive in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 32 bit system. So I have downloaded [dislocker](https://github.com/Aorimn/dislocker) (`dislocker-master.zip`).

The extracted zip file compiled and installed Dislocker on Ubuntu according to the instruction given in `INSTALL.md` file. To use Dislocker they have written as

> Once installed, see `dislocker(1)` for details on how to use it.

in `INSTALL.md` file but I cannot find `dislocker(1)` anywhere in the extracted zip file. So I searched on Google that how to use it and I found tutorial on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n7XT5fK4iwA.

According to this, last line in terminal

```
sudo mount -o loop /media/drive1/dislocker-file /media/mount1/
```

shows the error:

```
ntfs-3g-mount: mount failed: Permission denied
```

To fix this, I searched on Google and found a command on https://github.com/Aorimn/dislocker/issues/86, so I used the command:

```
sudo mount -o ro,loop /media/drive1/dislocker-file /media/mount1/
```

which opens the Bitlocker-encrypted drive as read-only. But I want *write access* also. How can I do that?

Things I have tried:

```
$ sudo chown  jin:jin drive1 
chown: changing ownership of 'drive1': Function not implemented

$ chmod 777 drive1/
error: chmod: changing permissions of 'drive1/': Function not implemented
```

I have also checked [Use (Windows) BitLocker-encrypted drive on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617950/use-windows-bitlocker-encrypted-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts/617989#617989) with result (my password is starting with 1):

```
$ sudo dislocker -r -V /dev/sda3 -123*** -- /media/drive1
dislocker: invalid option -- '1'
dislocker by Romain Coltel, v0.7.1 (compiled for Linux/x86)

Usage: dislocker [-hqrsv] [-l LOG_FILE] [-O OFFSET] [-V VOLUME DECRYPTMETHOD -F[N]] [-- ARGS...]
    with DECRYPTMETHOD = -p[RECOVERY_PASSWORD]|-f BEK_FILE|-u[USER_PASSWORD]|-k FVEK_FILE|-c

Options:
    -c, --clearkey        decrypt volume using a clear key (default)
    -f, --bekfile BEKFILE
                          decrypt volume using the bek file (on USB key)
    -F, --force-block=[N] force use of metadata block number N (1, 2 or 3)
    -h, --help            print this help and exit
    -k, --fvek FVEK_FILE  decrypt volume using the FVEK directly
    -l, --logfile LOG_FILE
                          put messages into this file (stdout by default)
    -O, --offset OFFSET   BitLocker partition offset, in bytes (default is 0)
    -p, --recovery-password=[RECOVERY_PASSWORD]
                          decrypt volume using the recovery password method
    -q, --quiet           do NOT display anything
    -r, --readonly        do not allow to write on the BitLocker volume
    -s, --stateok         do not check the volume's state, assume it's ok to mount it
    -u, --user-password=[USER_PASSWORD]
                          decrypt volume using the user password method
    -v, --verbosity       increase verbosity (CRITICAL errors are displayed by default)
    -V, --volume VOLUME   volume to get metadata and keys from

    --                    end of program options, beginning of FUSE's ones

  ARGS are any arguments you want to pass to FUSE. You need to pass at least
the mount-point.

Tue Aug 22 14:16:09 2017 [CRITICAL] Failed to open : No such file or directory
*** Error in `dislocker': corrupted size vs. prev_size: 0x816bb090 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x67377)[0xb755c377]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6d2f7)[0xb75622f7]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6d6ce)[0xb75626ce]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6e395)[0xb7563395]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(_IO_setb+0x61)[0xb7560171]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(_IO_file_close_it+0xa3)[0xb755e8b3]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(fclose+0x89)[0xb7552a69]
/usr/local/lib/libdislocker.so.0.7(dis_stdio_end+0x2b)[0xb76b1150]
/usr/local/lib/libdislocker.so.0.7(dis_destroy+0x68)[0xb76af4cf]
/usr/local/lib/libdislocker.so.0.7(dis_initialize+0xe6)[0xb76af5c8]
dislocker(main+0xe8)[0x80095eb2]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf7)[0xb750d637]
dislocker(+0x951)[0x80095951]
======= Memory map: ========
80095000-80097000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 550017     /usr/local/bin/dislocker-fuse
80097000-80098000 r--p 00001000 08:06 550017     /usr/local/bin/dislocker-fuse
80098000-80099000 rw-p 00002000 08:06 550017     /usr/local/bin/dislocker-fuse
816bb000-816dc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b6f00000-b6f21000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6f21000-b7000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b707b000-b7097000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1588       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b7097000-b7098000 rw-p 0001b000 08:06 1588       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b70ae000-b70b0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b70b0000-b7103000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1620       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
b7103000-b7104000 r--p 00052000 08:06 1620       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
b7104000-b7105000 rw-p 00053000 08:06 1620       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
b7105000-b710e000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1560       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.23.so
b710e000-b710f000 r--p 00008000 08:06 1560       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.23.so
b710f000-b7110000 rw-p 00009000 08:06 1560       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.23.so
b7110000-b7137000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7137000-b71c1000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 528942     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.3.0
b71c1000-b71c2000 r--p 00089000 08:06 528942     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.3.0
b71c2000-b71c3000 rw-p 0008a000 08:06 528942     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.3.0
b71c3000-b71c4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b71c4000-b746a000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 535258     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libruby-2.3.so.2.3.0
b746a000-b746e000 r--p 002a5000 08:06 535258     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libruby-2.3.so.2.3.0
b746e000-b746f000 rw-p 002a9000 08:06 535258     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libruby-2.3.so.2.3.0
b746f000-b7476000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7476000-b74cd000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 535153     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmbedcrypto.so.2.2.1
b74cd000-b74ce000 ---p 00057000 08:06 535153     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmbedcrypto.so.2.2.1
b74ce000-b74d0000 r--p 00057000 08:06 535153     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmbedcrypto.so.2.2.1
b74d0000-b74d1000 rw-p 00059000 08:06 535153     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmbedcrypto.so.2.2.1
b74d1000-b74d3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b74d3000-b74ec000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1694       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
b74ec000-b74ed000 r--p 00018000 08:06 1694       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
b74ed000-b74ee000 rw-p 00019000 08:06 1694       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
b74ee000-b74f0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b74f0000-b74f3000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1574       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
b74f3000-b74f4000 r--p 00002000 08:06 1574       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
b74f4000-b74f5000 rw-p 00003000 08:06 1574       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
b74f5000-b76a5000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1550       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
b76a5000-b76a7000 r--p 001af000 08:06 1550       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
b76a7000-b76a8000 rw-p 001b1000 08:06 1550       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
b76a8000-b76ab000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b76ab000-b76c7000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 550014     /usr/local/lib/libdislocker.so.0.7.1
b76c7000-b76c8000 r--p 0001b000 08:06 550014     /usr/local/lib/libdislocker.so.0.7.1
b76c8000-b76c9000 rw-p 0001c000 08:06 550014     /usr/local/lib/libdislocker.so.0.7.1
b76c9000-b76f8000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1587       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfuse.so.2.9.4
b76f8000-b76f9000 ---p 0002f000 08:06 1587       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfuse.so.2.9.4
b76f9000-b7702000 r--p 0002f000 08:06 1587       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfuse.so.2.9.4
b7702000-b7703000 rw-p 00038000 08:06 1587       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfuse.so.2.9.4
b7718000-b771b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b771b000-b771d000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0          [vvar]
b771d000-b771f000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
b771f000-b7741000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1522       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
b7741000-b7742000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7742000-b7743000 r--p 00022000 08:06 1522       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
b7743000-b7744000 rw-p 00023000 08:06 1522       /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
bff87000-bffa8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What does it mean? I tried the command for key recovery key,

```
$ sudo dislocker -r -V /dev/sdaX -p1536987-000000-000000-000000-000000-000000-000000-000000 -- /media/bitlocker
```

and password,

```
$ sudo dislocker -r -V /dev/sda3 -u -- /media/drive1
```

which worked fine but the command

```
$ mount -r -o loop dislocker-file /media/mount
```

with `-r` option does *not* give any error but opens the drive in *read-only* mode and without `-r` option gives same error: permission denied.

I also checked the comment:

> Dislocker should support read-write (rw) access to some Bitlocker containers/versions, "the source" link says windows 8 rw access wasn't supported yet" (in 2014) and a comment says it would silently mount as ro (even though mount shows as rw)" probably leading to the mount error `ntfs-3g-mount: mount failed: Permission denied`. Omitting the `-r` option to Dislocker & mount should try mounting rw

<sup>– [Xen2050 Jan 25 at 10:45](/questions/617950/use-windows-bitlocker-encrypted-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts/617989#comment1361376_617989)</sup>

But does not understand any. Does it mean that drive encrypted with bitlocker of windows 7 can open in write mode? I tried with the drive encrypted with bitlocker of windows 7 but it also throws the same error and opens only in read mode.  Now how can I enable write access in my Bitlocker-encrypted drive with Ubuntu?

Comment: Could you please provide a source for the statement by Xen2050? If the statement is true it appears that in 2014 it was impossible to mount Bitlocker volumes created with Windows 8 or later with Dislocker. In any case you should leave out the `-r` flags when invoking `dislocker` and `mount` as well as the mount option `ro`. `dislocker(1)` refers to the manual entry for `dislocker` in the manual section 1, which you can view with `man 1 dislocker` or simply `man dislocker` if you installed Dislocker.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Source for the statement by Xen2050: https://askubuntu.com/questions/617950/use-windows-bitlocker-encrypted-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts/617989#617989. When leaving out the -r flags when invoking dislocker and mount as well as the mount option ro, it shows error of permission denied as I have written in the post.

Comment: @DavidFoerster In August 2017, check http://www.hsc.fr/ressources/outils/dislocker/download/README.md, they have stated that "This software has been designed to read BitLocker encrypted partitions under a
Linux system. The driver has the capability to **read/write** on:
 - Windows Vista, 7, 8, 8.1 and 10 encrypted partitions - that's AES-CBC,
   AES-XTS, 128 or 256 bits, with or without the Elephant diffuser, encrypted
   partitions; " but actually write permission is not supported by dislocker yet i.e. in August 2017 even though they are mentioning that this is suppoerted.

Comment: @DavidFoerster you can also check hsc.fr/ressources/outils/dislocker/download/CHANGELOG.md, which states that " # v0.6
- Features improvement:
    - **Read/write** on Windows 10 (v1511) encrypted volumes - AES-XTS 128/256. " But this feature is not actually supported yet i.e. August, 2017.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I have tried all the suggestions from your previous comment and also have written in both my post and my comment that  "When leaving out the -r flags when invoking dislocker and mount as well as the mount option ro, it shows error of permission denied as I have written in the post"

Comment: Did you ever have any luck getting this to work? I'm in the same boat.

Comment:  I was running `dislocker -r`, which puts it in read-only mode. Nothing was wrong with my `mount` command. Herp derp.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this to mount the dislocker-file as a loop device and give everyone permission to write to it:

```
sudo mount -o loop,umask=0,uid=nobody,gid=nobody /media/drive1/dislocker-file /media/mount1
```

Comment: Worked using `gid=nogroup` instead of `gid=nobody`.

Answer (score 0):

If you did not figure this out by now,

`mkdir /media/dislocker 
 mkdir /media/windows`

Make sure here you don't use the -r option 
`dislocker -V /dev/sdax -pxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx -- /media/dislocker`

`mount -o loop /media/dislocker/dislocker-file /media/windows`

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, to this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/990558/345147) you can mount the `/media/drive1/dislocker-file` with any uid, gid you like, e.g.:

```
sudo mount -o loop,uid=<myUserId>,gid=<myGroupId> /media/drive1/dislocker-file /media/mount1
```

Then, you can access any file in `/media/mount1` from your user account.

Answer (score 0):

If `sudo mount -o ro,loop /media/drive1/dislocker-file /media/mount1/` it's because `ro` means read-only. Change it it `rw` and you should obtain write access.