# Data recovery cant mount windows disk

Tags: mount, data-recovery

I try to recover data but I cant know chich filesystem is being used.
I see the disk named sda in lsblk.

**I tried :**

```
sudo fsck /dev/sda
```

Gives me

```
The superblock could not be read ir dies not describe a valid ext...
```

And I tried with every magic number given by mke2fs -n /dev/sda

I also tried

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o ro /dev/sda /media/usr/external
```

Gives me

```
NTFS Signature is missing. Failed to mount...
```

Using ntfsfix I get the same error

**EDIT**
The PC which cant boot anymore is running windows 7 but I don’t know the filesystem used

I try to recover using Ubuntu running live on usb key. These are commands I tried since the creation of the post :

```
$ sudo parted -l
Error: /dev/sda: unrecognized disk label


$ mount -t vfat /dev/sda /media/usr/external
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda
```

The drive is not encrypted according to the owner of the PC.

I did not tried to modify windows files because I cant have access to it

Still blocked, any idea ?

Comment: You've made no mention of OS/release details, so why ask here?

Comment: Please click [edit] to let us know these facts. 1) Which OS is installed (Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Ubuntu Kylin, Ubuntu Budgie, et al.)? 2) Which release number?  3) Please run _sudo parted -l` . Highlight the text to select it, copy the text, then come back here and paste that into your question. || Please do not use Add Comment; Comments are a channel from us to you, whereas the Question should contain all the facts you have about the issue.

Comment: Have you tried `mount -t vfat /dev/sda /media/usr/external`?

Comment: Maybe your drive is encripted: https://askubuntu.com/a/1001327/925971

Comment: Did you try to modify the windows file when it was on hibernate using Linux, it usually corrupts  the NTFS system