# Dislocker error"Sun May 13 15:01:29 2018 [CRITICAL] Failed to open /etc/localtime: No such file or directory"

Tags: mount, encryption, data-recovery, disk, password-recovery

I installed the dislocker all correctly from github and I followed [these steps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617950/use-windows-bitlocker-encrypted-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) to mount my bitlcoker encrypted volume (its `/dev/sda5`). Now after running this command

```
$ sudo dislocker -V /dev/sda5  -mypassword -- /media/bitlocker
dislocker: invalid option -- 'b'

Sun May 13 15:01:29 2018 [CRITICAL] Failed to open /etc/localtime: No such file or directory
```

What could be the problem?

I have followed every step described in the link and made directories as mentioned there. My guess is that this error is related to directories and their path.

I'm using ubuntu 17.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got two errors here:

```
dislocker: invalid option -- 'b'
```

I'm guessing that your password begins with `b` and you've typed in the password directly after the dash, so `-mypassword` is more like `-boyMyPasswordIsReallySecureCorrectHorseBatteryStaple`. The option for entering a password is `-u` followed by the password, or `-p` followed by the recovery password. I'm assuming that you're not using the recovery password, so your command line should look like

```
sudo dislocker -V /dev/sda5  -uboyMyPasswordIsReallySecureCorrectHorseBatteryStaple -- /media/bitlocker
```

The second error is `Failed to open /etc/localtime: No such file or directory`... obviously, your `/etc/localtime` is missing. This should be a symbolic link to the actual file in `/usr/share/zoneinfo`. Read through  `man timedatectl` and `man 5 localtime`; see the 'Setting Time Zone' part of https://linoxide.com/linux-command/timedatectl-change-time-date-systemd/ for an example.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error using a linux live cd. The file is there, but i guess dislocker does not work with live cd and cannot find the file as it is not an actuall installation. That's a big fail for dislocker, its making it quite uselss