# I can't write (only read) on USB device encrypted with Bitlocker

Tags: permissions, mount, encryption

I installed Bitlocker/Dislocker on my Ubuntu 18.04 to access my USB pen-drive, that is encrypted with Bitlocker, according to
 [Use (Windows) BitLocker-encrypted drive on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/a/617989/230083).

It works out if I only have to read files, it doesn't if I try to write them on the mounted folder.

These are the commands I run:

```
sudo dislocker -V /dev/sda1 -u -- /media/bitlocker
sudo su -
cd /media/bitlocker
sudo mount -o loop,rw dislocker-file /media/mount
```

The `dislocker-file` got its `rw` attributes:

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1064271872 Jan  1  1970 dislocker-file
```

The files in `/media/mount` didn't:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  6316 May 12 18:02 'archive'*
```

only root is in full control with `rwx`.

I tried to apply `chmod 777 archive` , too, I got no errors but also nothing changed in `archive` file attrubutes.

Maybe the problem is only the mount command but I am not able to find it out.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [dislocker's readme](https://github.com/Aorimn/dislocker/blob/master/README.md) (important parts highlighted by me):

> `dislocker-fuse:` binary using FUSE to dynamically decrypt the
>   BitLocker-ed partition. You have to give it a mount point where, once
>   keys are decrypted, a file named dislocker-file appears. **This file is
>   a virtual NTFS partition, so you can mount it as any NTFS partition
>   and then read from or write to it.**

...and, in the notes section:

> `dislocker-fuse:` the one you're using when calling `dislocker'

So, as you correctly guessed, the problem boils down to:

### How to mount an ntfs partition writable by my user (or everyone)

This question has been asked and answered several times on AskUbuntu. In short:

To change the owning user or group, use the `uid` and/or `gid` options. For example: Assuming that your user has uid and gid 1000 (default ids of the first user created in Ubuntu), you could do:

```
mount -o loop,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000 dislocker-file /media/mount
```

Alternatively, you can change the `umask` to not restrict permissions at all:

```
mount -o loop,rw,umask=0 dislocker-file /media/mount
```

By the way, since you switched to the root user with `sudo su -`, you can omit `sudo` from the mount command.

Comment: Your solution solved my problem, thank you very much Danzel.