# Cant mount my windows(10) drive on to ubuntu(18.04 LTS) (dual boot)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount

When i try to mount:

```
harsh@harshs:/$ sudo mount dev/sda5 /media/windows 
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda5': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda5' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

Also ntfsfix doesnt work:

```
harsh@harshs:/$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda5
Mounting volume... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Invalid argument
NTFS signature is missing.
Trying the alternate boot sector
Unrecoverable error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
```

On windows its working fine but on ubuntu i can't find a way to access it
[Disk partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXHKM.png)

I also tried
sudo dislocker -r -V /dev/sdaX -uPASSWORD -- /media/bitlocker
Output of this:

```
Wed Dec  9 13:58:24 2020 [CRITICAL] None of the provided decryption mean is decrypting the keys. Abort.
Wed Dec  9 13:58:24 2020 [CRITICAL] Unable to grab VMK or FVEK. Abort.
```

Comment: sda 5 is a bitlocker encrypted drive according to the image provided (https://askubuntu.com/questions/617950/use-windows-bitlocker-encrypted-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Comment: @wraith3690001 is there no way i can mount it on my ubuntu and access windows files?

Comment: at the link I provided the first answer should provide you with the answer on how to mount it

Comment: I am completely new to this and I dont know where to find the recovery password. Is the recovery password the same as the password I enter when I logon to Ubuntu 18.04 ( as my windows I havent set any password)? And if its different how to get that recovery password?

Comment: You can get the recovery password on Windows: https://superuser.com/questions/1438702/bitlocker-how-to-create-recovery-key

Comment: I did this and when I tried to log on to my ubuntu it showed no hard disk detected and it wont start.