# Can't open Samsung T5 SSD on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: usb, kubuntu, ssd

I'm not able to open my Samsung T5 500GB disk on Ubuntu 18.04. I was able to open it before without problem. The device is shown on `dmesg` and `lsusb` command, but is not recognized by the Device Manager. It is also not accessible in Dolphin file manager.
I can see the SSD in GParted.

[image: Samsung T5 SSD in GParted]

The device is not encrypted as it is opening on Windows without any problem.

Is there any way to make this disk readable again on Linux?

Comment: It's encrypted by Windows using Bitlocker. I assume it was encrypted by the same Windows installation in which you're mounting the drive. Since it knows bitlocker and the key, it is mounted in Windows without any problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use (Windows) BitLocker-encrypted drive on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617950/use-windows-bitlocker-encrypted-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Comment: @yfluK I was able to open this SSD on 2 different Windows 10 PCs with different accounts without the need to decrypt or provide password. Don't know what would be the password to decrypt the device since I have never "officially" encrypted it.

Comment: In that case, try disable bitlocker from Windows. See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-security/want-to-remove-bitlocker-encryption-from-usb/8692d57e-7f93-438f-8195-f0141b8dc4ed